# PHPStorm Intellisense Does Not Recognize Constants Defined in Class

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to get PhpStorm intellisense to pick up these dynamically defined constants? Given the code below, PhpStorm gives the "Undefined constant SAMPLE_CONSTANT_THAT_WAS_DYNAMICALLY_DEFINED" error message.

```
class ExampleConfiguration
{
   private $configurationMapping;
   ...
   public function DefineConfigConstants()
   {
      foreach ($this->configurationMapping as $key => $value)
         define($key, $value);
   }
}

class ExampleClass
{
   public function Test()
   {
      print SAMPLE_CONSTANT_THAT_WAS_DYNAMICALLY_DEFINED;
   }
}
```

This issue can be tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11390, what I'm looking for is suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: So ... define them in a normal way in some separate file and place it anywhere in the project -- it will not be used by actual code when running -- only by IDE for its static analysis.

Comment: Can't do that. Constant names and values are definable by users in the system, so stored in the db.

Comment: Then where did you got `SAMPLE_CONSTANT_THAT_WAS_DYNAMICALLY_DEFINED` from if PhpStorm is complaining about it?

Comment: In any case: how do you expect PhpStorm to find out about those constants in first place .. if they are not even known to you because they are stored in DB? My only suggestion then: write custom script that create such `myconstants.php` (fetch info from DB) file where they will be defined in a normal way .. and run this script (update generated file) before working with the code in PhpStorm.

Comment: I'm just looking for suggestions and alternatives here. I'm well aware the PhpStorm can't find these. Yes your proposed solution would work. Anyone else have any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: @LazyOne please post your proposed solution as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE needs to know about such constants in order to not to complain about them. This means that they have to be defined in "normal" way (actual values do not matter, as long as they are not used for file names/paths in include/require statements).

**Suggestion:** write custom script that create such `myconstants.php` file where they will be defined in a normal way (since all such constants defined by users and stored in DB, you have to fetch them from DB yourself) .. and run this script (to update generated file) before working with the code in PhpStorm.